# SOAP digitally signed XML

Tags: xml, soap, pem, xml-signature

I am having trouble with soap messaging. I have my xml request but I need it to be digitally signed. I have certificate.pem but I dont know to implement it in the XML structure. My  should look like this but with the appropriate Values from the certificate:
                 `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:exc14n="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
      <S:Header>
        <To xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">Some Value</To>
        <Action xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">Some Value</Action>
        <ReplyTo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
          <Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</Address>
        </ReplyTo>
        <MessageID xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">Some Value</MessageID>
        <wsse:Security S:mustUnderstand="1">
          <wsu:Timestamp xmlns:ns17="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2006/02/addressingidentity" xmlns:ns16="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-secureconversation/200512" xmlns:ns15="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" wsu:Id="_3">
            <wsu:Created>2012-03-20T17:58:27Z</wsu:Created>
            <wsu:Expires>2012-03-20T18:03:27Z</wsu:Expires>
          </wsu:Timestamp>
          <wsse:BinarySecurityToken xmlns:ns17="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2006/02/addressingidentity" xmlns:ns16="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-secureconversation/200512" xmlns:ns15="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary" wsu:Id="URI">Some Value</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
          <ds:Signature xmlns:ns17="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2006/02/addressingidentity" xmlns:ns16="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-secureconversation/200512" xmlns:ns15="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" Id="_1">
            <ds:SignedInfo>
              <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
                <exc14n:InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="wsse S"/>
              </ds:CanonicalizationMethod>
              <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
              <ds:Reference URI="#_5002">
                <ds:Transforms>
                  <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
                    <exc14n:InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="S"/>
                  </ds:Transform>
                </ds:Transforms>
                <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
                <ds:DigestValue>Some Value</ds:DigestValue>
              </ds:Reference>
              <ds:Reference URI="#_3">
                <ds:Transforms>
                  <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
                    <exc14n:InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="wsu wsse S"/>
                  </ds:Transform>
                </ds:Transforms>
                <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
                <ds:DigestValue>Some Value</ds:DigestValue>
              </ds:Reference>
            </ds:SignedInfo>
            <ds:SignatureValue>Some Value</ds:SignatureValue>
            <ds:KeyInfo>
              <wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
                <wsse:Reference URI="URI" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3"/>
              </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
            </ds:KeyInfo>
          </ds:Signature>
        </wsse:Security>
      </S:Header>`

I will be really grateful for all ur advices and suggestions.
Thank you!